# Angular2 Socket Issue

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, socket.io

Hi Im facing Error while working on Socket.io in Angular 2 I have imported Everything required in typings.json,System.comfig.js, and in Package.json files and im using it in .ts file by using below statement

```
import * as io from "socket.io-client";
```

everything is fine till Now when im loading the project i could see below error

> (index):18 Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading
>   http://localhost:1000/socket.io-client

Please Help Me

Answer (score 0):

use `npm install @types/socket.io-client --save`

see https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1278 for more info

Comment: sorry it is not helpful